# Mongoose querying a reference collection data using aggrigate/populate

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am a newbie in MongoDB and Express JS

I have a Product model looks like

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   title: String,
   brand_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'brand' },
   varient:[{
       country_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'countries'},
       max_retail_price : Number,
       profit_margin : Number
   }],
```

and  Order model

```
 const orderTransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       shop_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'shop' },
       brand_id:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'brand' },
       product_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product' },
       product_varient_id:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product.varient._id' },
       transaction_id:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'transaction' }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('order', orderTransactionSchema );
```

In my Product collection, each product can have multiple variants.
But in order collection, a user can order only one product variant under a product.

I am trying to display orders with particular product details and variant details, But the problem is when I try to display it using either populate/Aggregate I am getting all the variants in the response array. actually, I want only one product and variant details as in the order collection.

This is what I tried

```
order.aggregate([{ $match :{} },
{
   $lookup: {
     from: "products",
     localField: "product_id",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "product_data"
   }
},
 ]).exec(function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
 });
```

and I am getting the output as

```
{ _id: 5c8a010b8feeb875abc1b066,
   shop_id: 5c7d194ca10ea45c0c03a0ee,
   brand_id: 5c41a8c34272c61a176b7639,
   product_varient_id: 5c41a9f3f8e1e71aa75b4f32,
   transaction_id: 5c6670d5b6c63d0762c6cc77,
   product_id: 5c41aac4d45a731af564c433,
   product_data:
    [ { _id: 5c41aac4d45a731af564c433,
        brand_id: 5c41a8c34272c61a176b7639,
        image: 'test.jpg',
        varient:        //getting all the varients here
         [ { _id: 5c4ee531bc20b27948b3aa98,
             sell_rate_local: 66,
             country_id: 5c01149d3c20440a6b2e4928 },
           { _id: 5c4ee53bbc20b27948b3aa99,
             sell_rate_local: 66,
             country_id: 5c00e1697dd7a23f08bdae68 } ],
        __v: 0 } ] } ]
```

In the Order table, there is porduct_id and product_varient_id is there 
I want to populate only the product with product_varient_id.

I also tried something with Populate

```
order.find().
             populate([

                  { path: 'shop_id', model: 'shop',select : 'name accounts' },    //it works
                 { path: 'transaction_id', model: 'transaction' }, //it wrks                     
                { path: 'product_varient_id', model: 'product', select:'product.varient.name'},
                 ]).then(result =>
                 {
                    // console.log(result);
                 }).catch(err =>{

                //     console.log(err);
                 });
```

These are the sample product and order document

Order Document Sample :

```
{  
   "_id":"5c77a025d65a892f6acf1803",
   "shop_id":"5c7d194ca10ea45c0c03a0ee",
   "brand_id":"5c41a8b44272c61a176b7638",
   "product_varient_id":"5c41a9f3f8e1e71aa75b4f32",
   "buy_rate":10,
   "buy_rate_after_discount":20,
   "product_mrp":30,
   "sell_rate":40,
   "customer_mobile":123456789,
   "status":true,
   "transaction_id":"5c6670c9b6c63d0762c6cc76",
   "product_id":"5c41a95ff8e1e71aa75b4f30",
   "createdAt":"2019-02-28T08:47:33.097Z",
   "updatedAt":"2019-02-28T08:47:33.097Z",
   "__v":0
}
```

Product document Sample :

```
{  
   "_id":"5c41aac4d45a731af564c433",
   "recharge_type":[  
      "5c00d9cf7dd7a23f08bdae5e"
   ],
   "name":"25 OC - Product 1",
   "title":"First installation recharge",
   "description":"0.1 credit for first time installation",
   "offer_message":"Hi.. You got 0.1 credits..!!",
   "brand_id":"5c41a8c34272c61a176b7639",
   "buy_rate":20,
   "profit_margin":80,
   "image":"test.jpg",
   "varient":[  
      {  
         "_id":"5c4ee531bc20b27948b3aa98",
         "display_name":"testlia",
         "profit_margin":66,
         "max_retail_price":66,
         "sell_rate":66,
         "sell_rate_local":66,
         "country_id":"5c01149d3c20440a6b2e4928"
      },
      {  
         "_id":"5c4ee53bbc20b27948b3aa99",
         "display_name":"testrinu",
         "profit_margin":66,
         "max_retail_price":66,
         "sell_rate":66,
         "sell_rate_local":66,
         "country_id":"5c00e1697dd7a23f08bdae68"
      }
   ],
   "createdAt":"2019-01-18T10:30:28.991Z",
   "updatedAt":"2019-01-28T11:19:23.662Z",
   "__v":0
}
```

Comment: Could you post the sample documents from all the collections

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet I have already added a sample output I am getting from the query. The main problem is with the 'product' collection . In product collection I have a varient document. That means one product can have multiple varient. But in the order summery there is only one product varient purslchse. So I can't able to populate only the specific varient-id corresponding to that product order.

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet can u please answer...

Comment: If you could show some sample documents and the output you want, then only I can help you.

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet I will update the question

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet  can u please answer the question

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: Yes I am doing. please wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB 3.6 or above have new [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax

```
  db.orders.aggregate([{
      $lookup: {
        from: "products",
        let: {
          "productId": "$product_id",
          "productVarientId": "$product_varient_id"
        },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: {
              $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$productId" ]}
            }
          },
          { $addFields: {
              varient: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$varient",
                  as: "varient",
                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$productVarientId", "$$varient._id" ] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "product_data"
      }
    }])
```

You can check datasample [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kB4_5qcFVNf)

Comment: I need to put a condition inside match , but i need to check the match condition only if the condition array is not empty

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet  can u answer?

Comment: @Sibinfrancis  can you elaborate your point show I can help in it? as i can see if you want to match condition you can use it first stage in aggregation. If you want to modify output data. please share sample data.